# Something I loved the most

Tags: riddle, mathematics, cipher, calculation-puzzle

Below are some puzzles you need to solve to make a **4 letter** word.

1.

> ```
> 105 35
> 315 ?
> ```

2.

> ```
> I am the most important element in your surrounding.
> I was found by a Scottish physician.
> Who am I?
> ```

3.

> ```
> I am made up of 3 digits.
> When you add the digits in me you will get a total of 11 and when you multiply the digits in me you get 9.
> My all digits are less then 10 and last digit is divisible by 3. 
> What number am I?
> ```

When you have solved the above puzzles you will get some numbers and letters. **Decode** them, and you will get the required word.

Hint #1

> You can decode them in any order. After decoding you need to rearrange them to get the required word.

Hint #2

> Out of three puzzles, one puzzle will give you 2 identical letters.

Hint #3

> Visit my Stack Exchange Account.

Comment: For the $3$rd one, should we add and multiply the digits of that  number?

Comment: I have corrected that now check :)

Comment: There are multiple possibilities for the last one, how do we know which one it is?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil added more information :)

Comment: @Swati that sadly doesn't help as the definition of a digit is a number 0-9, so it's assumed they are less than 10, the three numbers it could be are (spoilers people sorry) 911, 191 or 119. How do we know which one?

Comment: ok done now it will be easy to find out @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: By solving the three puzzles, you will get: 1. a number 2. a letter 3. a number. When decoding them should they be in this order?

Comment: @tyui Added hint :) .

Comment: @Swati This puzzle is simply amazing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the puzzle is:

> **JAVA**

Puzzle 1:

> This is a puzzle of the form '105:315::35:?', i.e. '105 is to 315 as 35 is to ?' In this case, we see that we get 315 by tripling 105; do the same to 35 and we get the answer **105**. Note that the value of ASCII-105 is the letter '**I**'.

Puzzle 2:

> As noted by @ShavinshSharma, this describes Nitrogen, a gas first discovered and isolated by the Scottish physician Daniel Rutherford in 1772 (source: Wikipedia). A nitrogen molecule is written as '**N<sub>2</sub>**' i.e. we need *two copies* of the letter '**N**'.

Puzzle 3:

> The result of the mathematics here is the number **119**. Note that the value of ASCII-119 is the letter '**W**'.

Putting it all together:

> We have the four letters **I**, **N**, **N** and **W**.
>
>  If we apply rot-13 to these letters (shift them 13 places in the alphabet) we get the letters **V**, **A**, **A** and **J**.
>
>  This gives us an anagram of the word '**JAVA**', which - as a check of [the OP's profile page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/66237/swati) will tell you - is their 'favourite programming language', thus satisfying the title! (Note that @Rand'alThor had already made the same leap here, although I believe this answer now fully describes the logic behind the puzzle...)

Comment: Yes :) finally someone fully solved this .. :D

Answer (score 2):

1. > Traversing diagonals of the square, we can get from a 3-digit number to a 2-digit number by removing the middle digit: $315$ to $35$ and $105$ to $15$. So the answer could be $15$.
2. > As Shivansh Sharma found, the answer is Nitrogen, a chemical element with number $7$ in the periodic table.
3. > The number here must be $119$.

So we can break up the solution as

> $15,7,119$ or $15,7,11,9$

which decodes as

> OGKI. Does this or its anagrams mean anything?

Although I suspect there may be another level of decoding and the final answer should be

> JAVA, given the title and the OP's profile page.

Comment: Answer is right :D . Still decoding part is incorrect.Hint rot13(Unir n ybbx va Nfpvv gnoyr)

Comment: @Swati Are the three numbers correct? Or should some of those be letters, or something else entirely?

Comment: rot13(Lbh jvyy trg 2 ahzore naq 2 yrggre(nf nyernql tvira va uvag ohg urer lbh unir gb guvax yvggyr ovg zber ) . :) Gura qrpbqr ahzore , gura svanyyl lbh jvyy or yrsg jvgu 4 yrggref qrpbqr gurz lbh jvyy trg svany nafjre) .

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

1.

> Could be **105** or **945**

2.

> The most important element in our surroundings is **Nitrogen**, discovered by Rutherford, a Scottish Physician.

3.

> The 3 numbers are 9, 1, 1 together making **911**. (9 + 1 + 1 = 11, 9 * 1 * 1 = 9)

So overall I think

> We can get N from Nitrogen.
>  911 is one of the 8 N11 codes.
>  10-5(from 105) is a 10-code.
>  Something in that direction.

Comment: 119, and 191 are also possible answers for the last one however

Comment: sorry not right answer :) but some parts are correct

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil yeah but 911 seemed more plausible.

Comment: @ShivanshSharma true, but 119 could be used to give a chemical element and then the symbol etc

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I like you're thinking, however the symbol of the 119'th element is Uue. Which contains 3 letters, with the N found in Nitrogen you have already 4 letters and the number 105/945 isn't used. So it might be that only the U from this is used? The symbol of the 115th element is Db, not sure if we can make a word with that....